# Draw some expanding arrows

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, sequence

This challenge is about printing a series of growing ASCII-art arrows. I'll describe the pattern in words, but it might be easier to look at what the start of this series looks like:

```
>
<
->
<-
-->
<--
--->
<---
---->
<----
----->
<-----
------>
<------
...
```

An arrow with length n contains an arrowhead (`<` or `>`) and `n-1` dashes (`-`). A right-facing arrow has the dashes first, then a `>`. A left-facing arrow starts with `<`, and is followed by the dashes. The series consists of a length `n` right-facing arrow followed by a length n left-facing arrow, with n from 1 to infinity.

To complete the challenge, write a program or function that takes one input, an integer `i >= 1`, and outputs the first `i` arrows. Arrows are individual, not in right-left pairs, so for `i=3` you should output:

```
>
<
->
```

You can return a list of strings, or print them one after the other. If printing, the arrows must be delimited by some consistent delimiter, which doesn't have to be a newline as in the example.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/87614/42963).

Comment: Can we have spaces before/after each line?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yes, trailing whitespace is ok.

Comment: And heading whitespace?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yeah, that's fine.

Comment: @Pavel what if another delimiter is used? are trailing/leading delimiters fine too, as long as no other non-output characters appear?

Comment: @ASCII-only Yes, but only one leading/trailing delimiter. So if it's `|`, you can't start with `||||||`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
⇵-×<ｎ¹［↔｝］
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyMUY1LSVENyUzQyV1RkY0RSVCOSV1RkYzQiV1MjE5NCV1RkY1RCV1RkYzRA__,i=MTA_,v=8)

Comment: I don't know any Canvas, but is that an arrow-drawing builtin I see? `↔` kinda looks like it!

Comment: `↔` is the "reverse horizontally" built-in (also swapping `>` & `<`), sadly no arrow built-ins :p

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 69 bytes

```r
for(i in 1:scan()-1)cat('<'[i%%2],rep('-',i/2),'>'[!i%%2],'
',sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwdCqODkxT0NT11AzObFEQ91GPTpTVdUoVqcotUBDXVddJ1PfSFNH3U49WhEirs6lrlOcWmCrrq7539D4PwA)

- -5 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe
- -3 bytes thanks to @Robert S.

Comment: `strrep` coerces its second argument to `integer` so you can use `/` in place of `%/%`

Comment: you can also get rid of `a` entirely by indexing over `0...(n-1)` instead: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwdCqODkxT0NT11AzObFEQ91GPTpTVdUoVqe4pKgotUBDXVddJ1PfSFNH3U49WhEipc6lrlOcWmCrrq7539D4PwA)

Comment: I'm an idiot... thanks ! :D

Comment: @Giuseppe :also I just noticed the deleted question of Robert S. I can use rep instead of strrep and save 3 bytes...(facepalm)

Answer (score 8):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 81 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=0;i<n;)System.out.printf(i%2<1?"<%s%n":"%s>%n","-".repeat(i++/2));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BTsMwDIbvfQqrUqWW0sB2XLrtsBMHTjsiDiFLJpfWqRJnEpr67CWrYAfEwf5l//Znd@qimu70OeMwOs/QpVpExl7YSJrRkXiQme5VCPCqkOCaAYzxo0cNgRUnuTg8wZC88sge6fz2DsqfQ7WMArwQHxyFOBgPdjtTs7ta50skBtw@S2xJVsevwGYQLrIYE4JticW6Xe3ztggF5Zu8CLukj3mTC29Go7jEun5aV5WcZrmcuTMhQVNuYXXTuv79A@DvlZ5KhBoSvpI/I1Yorc2Y8PfWP1vJW8wpu8U0fwM)

### Explanations

```java
n->{                  // int-accepting consumer
 for(int i=0;i<n;)    //  for each i from 0 to n-1 included
  System.out.printf(  //   output on stdout with a pattern
   i%2<1              //    if i is even:
    ?"<%s%n"          //     use the left-arrow pattern
    :"%s>%n",         //    else: use the right-arrow pattern
   "-".repeat(i++/2)  //    fill the "%s" in the pattern with i/2 dashes, and increment i
  );                  // 
}                     //
```

Comment: [Consider removing static reference to System.out](https://tio.run/##TY6xboMwEIZ3nuKEhASluE3GGtKhU4dKlTJWHVxioqNwRvYRqYp4dnqkacRg/7r7P39ya06maA/fM/aD8wytzGpk7FQzUs3oSN3paF2iU@8eiffsrel1FNWdCQHeDBKcI4Bh/OqwhsCGJU4OD9BLlwqPdPz4BOOPIbugACsTuJGhgv1PYNsrGfSFeCV@cRTG3npoqpmK3blxPpVngNWjxpJ0JrAaFlOTYrItN89xmYSE4qc4CTvJ@7iIlbeDNZxinj9ss0xP85//JgOxyV3CZsk8//8iwE3fUYqQg3gzfe0aZeraDuK9rdb4dTlFy5nmXw)

Comment: @candied_orange That's not self-contained.

Comment: How about done [like this](https://tio.run/##TY5Ba4QwEIXv@RWDIGitaXePjbs99NRDobDH0kPqRhmrE0niQln87Xa0VjaQDJn35pvX6IvOm/P3hF1vXYCG/3II2MpqoDKgJXmnxK2IVr47pHAKzuhu03zQAcs/S6uplqcfH0wn7RCUEGWrvYc3jQRXAdAPXy2b15mLxTN0rCXMRKo/PkG72qeLFeCVwoslP3TGQXWYYDmUH6@VdQkHATw8KixIpbxL9nO2KsF4X@yeoyL2MUVPUeyPXO@jPJLO9EaHBLPsYZ@mahSTWtZsNGAcvwXs5ppl/zkANn5LCUIGDE7VqlVSl6XpGby1bu1rcxTzHadf)?

Comment: @candied_orange It's the same: the imports are required in the count.

Comment: Why doesn't `import java.util.function.*;` count?

Comment: Because I use a lambda, and lambda are independant of functions. I merely use a function to be able to call the lambda, but if I wrote a lambda-accepting method that isn't in `java.util.function`, it'd still be legal. `java.util.function` != lambda.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87128/discussion-between-candied-orange-and-olivier-gregoire).

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```
(`take`g">")
g p=p:('<':init p):g('-':p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAe69YJFAPnoMle0mHRNQWTZb0/W0zdxg1tSbZn2KuGWq6ijqUXQqwZzR610idJrDFYrTTyFaeQB088Et9wgoZNvlibqEMcZH5Bw)

Plain old recursion: start with string `p` = `">"`, collect `p`, a `<` in front of all but the last char of `p` and a recursive call with one `-` put in front of `p`. Take the first `n` items of this list.

Edit: -1 byte thanks to @xnor.

Comment: [A weird change](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAe69YJFAPnoMle0mHRNQWTZb0/W0zdxg1tSbZn2KuGWq6ijqUXQqwZzR610idJrDFYrTTyFaeQB088Et9wgoZNvlibqEMcZH5Bw) to save a byte.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

thanks to the and Jo King for fixing a bug.

```python
k=0
exec"print k%2*'<'+k/2*'-'+~k%2*'>';k+=1;"*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9vWgCu1IjVZqaAoM69EIVvVSEvdRl07Wx9I66pr14EF7NSts7VtDa2VtDLzCkpLNDT//7cEAA)

Comment: Your arrows have too many dashes; only every other one should lengthen by a dash.

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9vWgCu1IjVZqaAoM69E3UY9OlvVyCpWO1vfSEtdV10byNNSt1O3zta2NbRW0srMKygt0dD8/98SAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Commodore BASIC V2](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_Basic_V2) (C64), 94 bytes

```
0inputn:fOi=1ton:oniaN1gO1:?"<";
1on-(i<3)gO2:fOj=1.5toi/2:?"-";:nE
2on-nOiaN1gO3:?">";
3?:nE
```

Not entirely sure about the byte count, this is based on the text representation for typing the valid program. It's a bit shorter on disk (91 bytes) because BASIC V2 uses a "tokenized" representation of programs.

#### [Online Demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B%22controlPort2%22:%22joystick%22,%22primaryControlPort%22:2,%22keys%22:%7B%22SPACE%22:%22%22,%22RETURN%22:%22%22,%22F1%22:%22%22,%22F3%22:%22%22,%22F5%22:%22%22,%22F7%22:%22%22%7D,%22files%22:%7B%22arrows.prg%22:%22data:;base64,AQgcCAAAhU46gUmyMaROOpFJrzGJMTqZIjwiOwA9CAEAkasoSbMzKYkyOoFKsjEuNaRJrTI6mSItIjs6ggBQCAIAkauoSa8xiTM6mSI+IjsAWAgDAJk6ggAAAA==%22%7D,%22vice%22:%7B%22-autostart%22:%22arrows.prg%22%7D%7D)

Slightly "ungolfed":

```
0 inputn:fori=1ton:oniand1goto1:print"<";    :rem read n from user, loop to n, if odd skip "<"
1 on-(i<3)goto2:forj=1.5toi/2:print"-";:next :rem skip for i<3, print (i-1)/2 times "-"
2 on-notiand1goto3:print">";                 :rem if even skip ">"
3 print:next                                 :rem newline and next loop iteration
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Self-modifying Brainfuck](https://soulsphere.org/hacks/smbf/), 55 bytes

Take input as character code.
Only support input up to 255.
Use null character to separate lines.

Coincidentally, all arrow-drawing characters are used as BF commands. Unfortunately, it doesn't save any bytes (currently).

```
>>,[<<[-<.>>+<]<<.>>.+>>-[<<<<<.>>>>[-<+<.>>].>-<]>]<>-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7NCoMwEITveYpFLFFs4g/0tuyLaA4xKvZQI5qD0PbZ01V6mZ2dgY/p7T5HN29Z/hbr9lzCBEl3pNnf36rmgLTOE/EVzgZABDn6ScIH5tEOoJyqgcD5YYxE9xaxVaiJCjR4Xl0QKU7x@oi4LU5nNCk0ZJBUZJ7gBfBgaOnXUO6vfrrk4nIaNpBdJVkWGX8)

#### Explanation

```
 Code  |              Memory         | Output | Comment
-------+-----------------------------+--------+--------------------------
       | '<' '>' '-' [0]  0   0   0  |        |
>>,    | '<' '>' '-'  0   0  [x]  0  |        |
[      |                             |        |
       | '<' '>' '-'  l   0  [x]  0  |        | l = arrow length
<<[-<  |                             |        | copy l to next cell
.>>+<] |                             |        | and print '-'
       | '<' '>' '-' [0]  l   x   0  | -----  | there are l '-'s
<<.    | '<' [>] '-'  0   l   x   0  | >      |
>>.+   | '<' '>' '-' [1]  l   x   0  | <null> |
>>-    | '<' '>' '-'  1   l  [y]  0  |        | y=x-1
[      |                             |        | execute if y>0
<<<<<. | [<] '>' '-'  1   l   y   0  | <      |
>>>>   | '<' '>' '-'  1  [l]  y   0  |        |
[-<+<. |                             |        |
>>]    | '<' '>' '-'  L  [0]  y   0  | -----  | L=l+1
.      | '<' '>' '-'  L  [0]  y   0  | <null> |
>-<]>] |                             |        | decrement y
<>-    |                             |        | do nothing, used as data
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 17 bytes

```
m_W%d2+*\-/d2@"><
```

Output is a list of strings. Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m_W%25d2%2B%2A%5C-%2Fd2%40%22%3E%3C&input=8&debug=0).

```
m_W%d2+*\-/d2@"><"dQ   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
                       Trailing "dQ inferred
m                  Q   Map [0-Q), as d, using:
          /d2            Floored division of d by 2
       *\-               Repeat "-" the above number of times
      +                  Append to the above...
             @"><"d      Modular index d into "><" - yields ">" for even d, "<" for odd
                         - examples: d=4 gives "-->", d=7 gives "---<"
 _W                      Reverse the above if...
   %d2                   ... (d % 2) != 0
                       Implicit print result of the map
```

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>62</s> <s>56</s> 50 bytes

```powershell
param($n)(0..$n|%{($j='-'*$_)+'>';"<$j"})[0..--$n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPU8NAT08lr0a1WkMly1ZdV11LJV5TW91O3VrJRiVLqVYzGiivq6uSF/v//39TAA)

Loops from `0` up to input `$n`, each iteration creating two arrow strings. Those are then indexed with `0..--$n` to pull out the correct number of elements.

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to KGlasier.*

Comment: Messing around with my own solution I found a way to cut a few bytes on yours: Can save 4 bytes by wrapping the loop in brackets and indexing directly. ie `param($n)(0..$n|%{($j='-'*$_++)+'>';"<$j"})[0..--$n]`. So now you don't have to write `$x` twice.

Comment: Also you can save two more bytes by not using `++` in `($j='-'*$_++)` as you don't use `$_` anywhere else.

Comment: @KGlasier Awesome - thanks for the obvious golfs! :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>51</s> 44 bytes

<sup>-7 bytes thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) (using `iterate` over list-comprehension)!</sup>

```hs
(`take`do b<-iterate('-':)"";[b++">",'<':b])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxDoIwEADQX7l0KQRLdMXi4qoTo5pwhSsQSmna8/etLG97M6aVnMsWWnjnomdcqR93MFotTBGZCqlkUwpxfZmqEjdxklo25lPmDRd/rA3DE8KXO44PDzVYOIiEI7Raw0R83z2T55Qv599gHU4pqyGEPw)

### Explanation / Ungolfed

Using `do`-notation saves us a `concat`, and using infix-notation allows a pointfree function with `take`, undoing these would give:

```hs
f n = take n $ concat [ [b++">", '<':b] | b <- iterate ('-':) "" ]
```

Answer (score 5):

## Japt `-m`, <s>16</s> <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)*

```
g<i>)iUUz ç-
```

[Test it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ZzxpPilpVVV6IOct&input=MTAKCi1tUg==)

### Explanation:

```
-m            // Map the program through [0...Input); U becomes the iterative number
g<i>)iUUz ç-  
 <i>          // ">" prepended with "<", creating "><"
g             //   Get the char at index U, with index-wrapping
    i         // Insert:
     U        //   At index U, with index-wrapping
         ç-   //   "-" repeated:
      Uz      //     U/2 times
```

Comment: [12 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ZzxpPilpVVV6IOct&input=MTAKCi1tUg==)

Comment: @Shaggy Ha! Very clever, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 53 bytes

My first codegolf answer.

```
lambda x:[i%2*"<"+i//2*"-"+~i%2*">"for i in range(x)]
```

-10 bytes thanks to Jo King

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
ị⁾><;’H”-ẋƲṚ⁸¡)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//4buL4oG@Pjw74oCZSOKAnS3huovGsuG5muKBuMKhKf/Dhysv4oKsxZLhuZj//zM)

Comment: -1 byte using tie: [TIO](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//4buL4oG@Pjzhua07xq3igJlI4oCdLeG6i8ayKf/Dhysv4oKsxZLhuZj//zM).

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-m`, 14 bytes

```
"<>"¬hUUz ç-)q
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=Ijw+IqxoVVV6IOctKXE=&input=MTAKLVJt)

Updated with a completely new method.

Explanation:

```
                  #Implicitly map over the range [0..input) as U
"<>"              #The string "<>"
    ¬             #Split into the array ["<",">"]
     hU     )     #Replace the element at index U with wrapping:
           -      # The character '-'
          ç       # Repeated a number of times equal to
       Uz         #  U integer divided by 2
             q    #Join the array to a string
```

Comment: `ç` auto-casts its first parameter into a string, so you can drop the `'`.

Comment: You don't need the `u` method thanks to index wrapping so this can be 14 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Jo King and Kevin Cruijssen

```
{ï½'-*'>ï¥╛Å⌡\n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/68PpDe9V1tdTtgIylj6bOPtz6qGdhTN7//4amAA)

### Explanation

The 15-byte approach is different compared to my original solution, I can't take any credit for the implementation.

```
{                 start block or arbitrary length
 ï                index of current loop, or length of last loop
  ½               pop a : push(a//2 if int else a/2)
   '-             push single character "-"
     *            pop a, b : push(a*b)
      '>           push single character ">"
        ï         index of current loop, or length of last loop
         ¥        modulo 2
          ╛       if without else
           Å      start block of length 2
            ⌡     decrement twice
             \    swap top elements
              n   newline char, or map array with newlines
```

Comment: How does the `if/else` work in MathGolf? I know how the if-without-else and else-without-if statements work, but how to create an if{ ... } else{ ... } in MathGolf with `¿`? (Maybe I should post this in the chat instead of here.. But I might perhaps have a save of 1 byte if I can fix the if-else.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I think it works with the next two commands/blocks. e.g. `¿12` will push 1 if true, else 2, `¿Å3*Å1+` will add one if true else triple the next element

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The if/else pops two operators or blocks from the code. Jo King is correct in his example, but you could also do `¿{"foo"}{"bar"}` or `¿1{2}`.

Comment: @JoKing I'll add a TODO to fix the docs for the slicing operators.

Comment: @JoKing Ah ok, thanks for the explanation. Forgot about the code-blocks of length `n` builtins up to size 8. In that case it's [a 17 bytes alternative as well](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/68PpDe9V1tYDU0kP7D3eq28QcblW3y/v/39AUAA).

Comment: I feel like `'>` should only count as one command, which would save a byte `:(`

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/68PpDe9V1tdTtgIylj6bOPtz6qGdhTN7//4amAA) using @KevinCruijssen's solution

Comment: @JoKing Ah nice. Didn't knew increment/decrement worked on characters as well in MathGolf. That's good to know. :)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>80</s> <s>77</s> <s>76</s> <s>74</s> 71 bytes

```c
g(n,i,j){--n&&g(n);for(j=n%2,i=n/=2;putchar(~n?n---i*j?45:62-j*2:0););}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfBCsIwDADQ@77CiyMpDbowPSyUfksp2LWwKENPo/569N1eppKzWQH11Tc8iHQc/0N5PHdoQc/sa9BLYHl93nlNO3w1KhFV1@J8W@5MzfFyRUHptqWqgKdjKMATytDtBw)

-3 bytes with idea from [ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/177454/draw-some-expanding-arrows/177688?noredirect=1#comment430683_177688).

-1 with `\0` instead of `\n`

-5 rearranging parts

---

Output includes a trailing `\0`.

```c
g(n,i,j){
    --n&&g(n);              //draw smaller arrows first (if n>1)
    for(j=n%2,i=n/=2;       //j:!(input parity); i:arrow len-1=ceil(input)/2-1
        putchar(~n          //if n>=0, arrow is not yet completed
                ? n---i*j   //if not first (j==1) or last (j==0) char of arrow:
                  ? 45      // output '-'
                  : 62-j*2  // otherwise, output the appropriate arrow head
                : 0););     //\0 after arrow complete. putchar returns 0; loop terminates
}
```

Comment: [this](https://tio.run/##DcxBCoMwEEDRvacogjKjGaRD68IheBYJNCbQqVhdiV49ZvfhwXfknUvJg5pgIh5a17npifL5rRBt22rFJljtLIsKLvvm5mkFIqWLQhPH13vomWLDKBn/UJYoZ/pOQQEfR@GB86w40w0) _might_ be clearer? idk

Comment: [so close :/](https://tio.run/##DcwxCoQwEEDR3lPYKBmTQR1cC0PWs0jAOAHHRdxK3Ktn0/3i8T0G71MKSgybCLfUdW7swa7HqaLTWioy7KR1ZERrKxY@38tvy5kZvnnuu0nwh9zEeXhNI2FsCOyT9oVFQXkXQVHeFU/6Aw)

Comment: @ASCII-only Yeah, that should be clearer, even if it doesn't make a difference for bytecount. As for that second point.. thanks for the idea! Managed to trim down to 78 with that.

Comment: [sadly, combining ternaries doesn't help](https://tio.run/##DcyxCoMwEADQ3a/QoXIXc4indmgIfosEjAl4LWInMb8e3d70HHnncvYgOuiIp9T1Y@rQLN8dom0aebEOVlrLJonB3/9w67wDkVCioOI0jNSPqkryeTNFxWiuvM1BAMuz8MDPVVz5Bg)

Comment: XD you still have `!n--` in the first codeblock

Comment: ah, thanks for the catch

Comment: [_might_ help? although probably won't](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9dI08nUydLszpPTQ3I1jXUtE7LL9LIstXWzlM10sm0zdO3NbKuy7PWLCgtSc5ILAKq0bVX0rWzUYrO063TzdTKsjewytI2jLUyNNC0rv2fm5iZp6GpUM2VrmEENIyr9j8A)

Comment: delimiter doesn't have to be newline. so you can change `10` to `0`

Comment: as far as I'm aware, none of the ascii characters from 0-9 count as whitespace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88168/discussion-between-ascii-only-and-attinat).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 58 bytes

Returns a space-separated string.

```javascript
n=>(g=p=>n--?k++&1?`<${p} `+g(p+'-'):p+'> '+g(p):'')(k='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k4j3bbA1i5PV9c@W1tbzdA@wUaluqBWIUE7XaNAW11XXdMKSNkpqIP4mlbq6poa2bZA8n9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqmmJheqiKGBpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>123</s> <s>122</s> 118 bytes

```
	N =INPUT - 1
P	H =X / 2
	Y =DUPL('-',H)
	OUTPUT =EQ(H,X - H) Y '>'	:S(I)
	OUTPUT ='<' Y
I	X =LT(X,N) X + 1	:S(P)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcqxCsIwEAbg@e4p/u0STJGKLmKcWkigxIgJXFZnsYPvT7Sb3/x93utzfR17pwQfU64FA0bOFOAVexyYGvxU82JkEBcs062Wrfn5boLTXw8WDXIVOj9M/AtyETSOpPBLMeqShWKHcXvZ8pwm6v30BQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 22 bytes

```
i>
<Àñäkjjé-já-ñÀGjdG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9OOy0b6cMPhjYeXZGdlHV6pm3V4oS6Q1@CeleL@//9/YwA)

Comment: This looks like some weird scandinavian language

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＮθＦθ«⊘ι↓>‖Ｔ»Ｆθ‖Ｔ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05orLb9IAchQqObiDCjKzCvR8EjMKUtN0cjUBEpChaxc8svzdBSU7JRAYkGpaTmpySUhRYl5xUDduRpAwVq4OVhk//83/69blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. I had three 17-byte solutions before I eventually stumbled over this one. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
Ｆθ«
```

Repeat `n` times, 0-indexed.

```
⊘ι
```

Draw a line of `-`s of length half the index (truncated).

```
↓>
```

Draw the arrowhead and move to the next line.

```
‖Ｔ»
```

Reflect everything, flipping the arrowheads.

```
Ｆθ‖Ｔ
```

The above loop has `n` reflections, but we need an even number of reflections, so perform another `n` reflections.

Answer (score 3):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>76</s> 73 bytes

```
import StdEnv,StdLib
$n=take n[s\\i<-inits['--'..],s<-[i++['>'],['<':i]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xDoIwFEV3v@INJNVACa6mOOlgwsZYOpRSzQvtw9hq4s/7JGG6OWc41wVvieMyvYOHaJEY43N5ZejzdKVPtU6H466gNtvZA@k0DKgkEuakhZSirk2VlNRYllqcham0UOKExhjus11DLdyDzQHJJ9hDAcemgQP/3GofieWt48uXbES3wXbIcvwD)

Uses the neat fact that `['-','-'..]` is the same as `['--'..]` to save a bit.

Answer (score 3):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), 49 bytes

```
00 C0 20 9B B7 A2 00 8A 4A A8 90 05 A9 3C 20 D2 FF A9 2D C0 00 F0 06 20 D2 FF 
88 D0 FA 8A 4A B0 05 A9 3E 20 D2 FF A9 0D 20 D2 FF E8 E4 65 D0 D7 60
```

Still quite a bit shorter than [BASIC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177468/71420) ;) This one has a number range only up to `255` because the natural integer size of the machine has only 8 bits.

#### [Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B%22controlPort2%22:%22joystick%22,%22primaryControlPort%22:2,%22keys%22:%7B%22SPACE%22:%22%22,%22RETURN%22:%22%22,%22F1%22:%22%22,%22F3%22:%22%22,%22F5%22:%22%22,%22F7%22:%22%22%7D,%22files%22:%7B%22arrows.prg%22:%22data:;base64,AMAgm7eiAIpKqJAFqTwg0v+pLcAA8AYg0v+I0PqKSrAFqT4g0v+pDSDS/+jkZdDXYA==%22%7D,%22vice%22:%7B%22-autostart%22:%22arrows.prg%22%7D%7D)

Usage: `SYS49152,[n]` (e.g. `SYS49152,3` for the example from the challenge)

**Commented disassembly**:

```
         00 C0       .WORD $C000        ; load address
.C:c000  20 9B B7    JSR $B79B          ; get unsigned byte from commandline
.C:c003  A2 00       LDX #$00           ; main loop counter
.C:c005   .loop:
.C:c005  8A          TXA                ; loop counter to accumulator
.C:c006  4A          LSR A              ; divide by 2, shift lowest bit to C
.C:c007  A8          TAY                ; result to Y
.C:c008  90 05       BCC .toright       ; C clear -> counter even, skip '<'
.C:c00a  A9 3C       LDA #$3C           ; load character '<'
.C:c00c  20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2          ; output character
.C:c00f   .toright:
.C:c00f  A9 2D       LDA #$2D           ; load character '-'
.C:c011  C0 00       CPY #$00           ; counter/2 == 0 ? then no dashes
.C:c013  F0 06       BEQ .skipdashes
.C:c015   .printdashes:
.C:c015  20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2          ; output character
.C:c018  88          DEY                ; decrement Y
.C:c019  D0 FA       BNE .printdashes   ; not 0 yet -> repeat
.C:c01b   .skipdashes:
.C:c01b  8A          TXA                ; loop counter to accumulator
.C:c01c  4A          LSR A              ; shift lowest bit to C
.C:c01d  B0 05       BCS .toleft        ; C set -> counter odd, skip '>'
.C:c01f  A9 3E       LDA #$3E           ; load character '>'
.C:c021  20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2          ; output character
.C:c024   .toleft:
.C:c024  A9 0D       LDA #$0D           ; load newline character
.C:c026  20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2          ; output character
.C:c029  E8          INX                ; next loop iteration
.C:c02a  E4 65       CPX $65            ; compare to command line argument
.C:c02c  D0 D7       BNE .loop          ; not reached yet -> repeat main loop
.C:c02e  60          RTS                ; exit
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 49 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>--n?f(n,l='')+(n%2?`
<`+l:`
${l+='-'}>`):'>'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VchBDsIgEADAO@/Q7G4oRuuNCHwFgmDabBYjphfj2@lVjzNr2lLPr@X5NtLuZYzqxHljJFSUiR0AaZTjHKK6Rc02qsOHtQMDXx/JgoeRm/TG5cTtgRWvROp3/lXxciYaOw)

Comment: Wow, pretty cool

Comment: ...but it throws on `10000`, meanwhile my ES6 solution is still works :D Anyway, your solution is very cool)

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 51 bytes

```powershell
param($n)0..$n|%{'-'*$_+'>';'<'+'-'*$_}|?{$n---gt0}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>23</s> 20 bytes

```
FNÉD„><è'-N;∍«s_iR},
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fze9wp8ujhnl2NodXqOv6WT/q6D20ujg@M6hW5/9/QwOD/wA)

First time using 05AB1E or any other golfing language for that matter. Any ideas welcome.

-3 from Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: Welcome to the world of 05AB1E, and nice first answer. +1 from me. :) `"><"` can be `„><` to save a byte. There are builtins for 1, 2, and 3 char strings, being `'`, `„`, and `…` respectively. Here is a [18 bytes alternative](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fTV3Xz/pRR6/f4Y5MdbvDq9VtDq@p9dL5/9/QFAA) I came up with, but perhaps it could be golfed a bit more. If you haven't seen it yet, we have a [tips for golfing in 05AB1E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/96361/52210) page, and also feel free to [ask anything in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33375/05ab1e-oasis).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks so much for your ideas. I don't feel right just using your code, as it feels fairly different from mine, but I did use the idea of modulo 2 as checking for if a number is odd. I also use the two char string idea. I would not mind at all if you posted the 18 byte version on your own.

Comment: I've [posted my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177573/52210) in that case. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 39 bytes

```perl6
{map {'<'x$_%2~'-'x$_/2~'>'x$_%%2},^$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzo3sUChWt1GvUIlXtWoTl0XxNAHMuzAIqpGtTpxKvG1/9M0jDXt7PSKEyutudI0jAygnP8A)

Anonymous code block that returns a list of lines.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>109</strike> 108 bytes

-1 byte thanks to NK1406

```
func[n][repeat i n[print reduce[pick[pad/with pad/left/with]k: i% 2 + 1
pick copy"<>"k i / 2 + k - 1 #"-"]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsIwEEX3OcVnxJWUEl0IRTxEt8MsSjLBEIkhpIinj7bu3ud9XlXfZ/UsJkw9rNlxFq5adGmIyFxqzA1V/eqUS3SJy@LHd2wPbPDU0PYlaUI84owTrNl@cK/yodud0q8z7iJhgMWBBhKRHnAx/zqRCbDX/gU)

Comment: -1 for [removing a space](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsIwEEX3OcVnxJWUEl0IRTxEt8MsSjLBEIkhpIinj7bu3ud9XlXfZ/UsJkw9rNlxFq5adGmIyFxqzA1V/eqUS3SJy@LHd2wPbPDU0PYlaUI84owTrNl@cK/yodud0q8z7iJhgMWBBhKRHnAx/zqRCbDX/gU "Red – Try It Online")

Comment: @NK1406 Thank you! I didn't know this is valid.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
{"<->"x#2,x{(1=*x)_1,2-|x}\0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlrJRtdOqULZSKeiWsPQVqtCM95Qx0i3pqI2xqD2f5qCocl/AA)

first we generate lists with 0 instead of `"<"`, 1 instead of `"-"`, and 2 instead of `">"`:

`{` `}` function with argument `x`

`x{`...`}\0` apply the inner function `x` times, starting with an initial value of `0` and preserving intermediate results

`|x` reverse

`2-` replace 0 with 2 and vice versa, keep the 1s as they are

`1,` prepend a 1

`(1=*x)_` is the first of `x` equal to 1? if yes, drop one element, otherwise drop 0 elements (do nothing)

`2,` prepend a 2 for the initial `">"` arrow

`x#` we have a little too many lists, so take only the first `x` of them

`"<->"` use the lists' elements (0/1/2) as indices in this string

Comment: I would like to ask for an explanation (I haven't started learning K yet, I don't know which version to start with...)

Comment: @GalenIvanov i tried to write an explanation, i hope it makes sense. thanks for your interest in my favourite language :) there are multiple implementations with different advantages and disadvantages ([kx's original](https://kx.com/download/), [kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), [oK](https://github.com/johnearnest/ok) and i'm working on my own). would you like to join the [apl chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) so i can give you more details?

Comment: Thank you, I'm already there

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>127</s> 95 + 26 = 121 bytes

```c
i,j;f(x){for(i=0;i<x;putchar(10),i+=2){for(j=0;E;printf(">\n%c",x-i-1?60:9);for(j=0;x-i-1&&E;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc1BCsIwFATQuxQsPyTBtlRBf6Mbews3IZD6g8YSKwQkVzdWpdt5M4yRgzE5k3BoIbKXvQcgVSF1EcfnZC46QF0xQVw1f3Wz9jgG8pOF4nD2K1OIKEnWx2213zFcSr@sLHtMKd80eZj38HVoGab8Nvaqh0eWp165jtYNcu7Y8tlu2Ac)

Compile with `-DE=j<i/2;++j)putchar(45)`

-6 bytes from [Logern](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/177454/draw-some-expanding-arrows/177571?noredirect=1#comment427198_177571)

Yay mismatched parentheses!

Ungolfed:

```c
void f(int x) {
	for (int i = 0; i < x; i += 2) {
		for (int j = 0; j < i/2; ++j) {
			printf("-");
		}
		printf(">\n");
		if (x - i - 1) { // Test for last loop: only print <-- if x is even
			printf("<");
			for (int j = 0; j < i/2; ++j) {
				printf("-");
			}
		}
		else {
			printf("\t"); // This is the 9 in the x-i-1?60:9
		}
		printf("\n");
	}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/LDoIwEEXX8BU3rkpIg7owKqA/4dKNwVaHYGuEkBrDt@NQTHysTDqZR8/M3CnkqSj6vrV0hBZkGrgIjzDQ9gafEnJMU3YZ3ODiHHNPvJFyREpGKJmniONyJILrjf@1mMhJlHLehe/SZm/GImkIB8mjJWbchyTBTtUNhvnVgYPK2usa1lR3@G5kknENB6qhWmU@V2Xj1H/U/crz@gZTVa2@D9g3jHhlZ97JrzkrrEDGB06SnG0X0/Xq58jXjV04FIP@ciAjoocWyyjt@ic)

Comment: [121 bytes with a -D compiler flag instead of #define - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc3RCsIgGAXgdxk0FJXcqKD@WTf5Ft2I4PqlbNgCIXz1TIrdnu8cjhWjtaUg9@BIom/3iASVBBwSTK/ZXk0knaQcmer/6qtqmCKG2ZHmeAkr2/AkUHSnnTzsKSylX9a2GnIud4OB1D2pnsvHupsZn0WctfIDrntgzNPlbrOlXw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Another -3 bytes by taking out the i=0 like [this](https://tio.run/##NY3bCsIwEET/pWBJSIJpUUG30RfzF76UhdQNGkusEJD8uvFGX2fOnEE1IJZC0oNjiT/dLTKgLsH4mPDcR9ZoLkmY9l95o8HCGClMjlX7U1hgJZMi1Rw2erflMEO/rK4t5FyuPQX22X9dkMsL3aUf7kUdrfEdLVsQwvP5b7Xmbw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @NK1406 [Functions have to be reusable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/do-function-submissions-have-to-be-reusable), that edit would break this rule. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BCsIwFAXXeoyCJaENpqUK@hvdmFu4CYHUHzSWWCFQcnVjtXQ1MG8WT7NO65SwtGBIoKN5egLYBujfg74pTypOSyxEPU9WcJDQe3SDIdnp6jY6KwNDVp33/HigsER/l@cSYkwPhY7Qcb0yZCp@aGbUfGJMH23uqnsldpHCtritoSgsXQ40O/oF "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @pizzapants184 Sorry, didn't see that!

Comment: Suggest `x+~i` instead of `x-i-1` and `i+=puts(" ")` instead of `putchar(10),i+=2`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>18</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
F'-N;∍'>«º2äNè,
```

Suggested as a golf for [*@nedla2004*'s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177490/52210), but he said I should post it myself since it's using a slightly different approach.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fTV3Xz/pRR6@63aHVh3YZHV7id3iFzv//hqYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
F                # Loop `N` in the range [0, (implicit) input):
   N;            #  Halve the current index `N`
 '-  ∍          '#  Have that many "-" (the halved index decimal .5 is ignored)
      '>«       '#  And append a ">"
         º       #  Now mirror it: i.e. "--->" becomes "---><---"
          2ä     #  Split it into two equal-sized parts: i.e. ["--->","<---"]
            Nè   #  Index the `N` into this array of two strings (with automatic wraparound)
              ,  #  And output it with a trailing newline
```

Comment: You could probably make something work with `NÈ„><è`

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Not sure I could use that, since one had to be prepended, and the other appended (hence the use of an if-else). But, I have been able to golf 3 bytes using a different approach now with a mirror `º` and splitting into two equal parts `2ä`. :)

Comment: Your TIO link isn't right now :P

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Oops.. fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## ES6, <s>96</s> <s>82</s> <s>79</s> 70 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclRCsIwDADQf48REBLmou5TbMVzjOHC7CRjS0s3BE9fBd/vm@Qt65A1bbXFZyijK@Z8y8z3nOWDRh0vkhAfByXnUffNDa5wAaAKauAcUpAN9dhQ9c/feSAqQ7Q1zoHn@MIRzyfiKar1u57KFw) (Thanks to @Oliver)

```
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>(i%2?"<":"")+"-".repeat(i/2)+(i%2?"":">"))
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! By default, taking input as a variable is disallowed; you have to either make it a function (just stick a `i=>` in front of your code!) or from a command-line argument or STDIN or something.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino okay, edited answer. However, the most voted answer contains only the body of the function, but ok. Anyway I'm outsider)

Comment: Can you link it? I don't think any of them are invalid, at least not the top few.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177465/84533

Comment: @HyperNeutrino well, maybe I'm just not familiar with this language and he has bash input inside the code with some way :)

Comment: `scan()` is input in R :)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino already googled and got it, sorry! :)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and nice first answer :) Here are a couple ways you can save some bytes: [Try it Online](https://tio.run/##LclBCsIwEADAu89YWtgFu2qPYiK@Q8SEmkpKmw1pKUjJ26MH5zqDXe3cJR@XJsjLlV6VoPSdmW8p2Q8GevBkI@Jz70lpU22@bq9wgTNArjZogJOLzi7oDy3lf/9WQzbEg/hgdqZ0EmYZHY/yxh5PR6LyBQ)

Comment: @Oliver thank you :)

Comment: A few more bytes: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##HclRCsIwDADQf48REBJ0UfcptuI5xnBhdpKxpaUbgqevw9/3RvnI0mdNa2XxFcrgijnfMPMjZ/miUcuzJMTnUcl51H19hxtcAeiAUAHnkIKsqKeaNvn3th6IeIxq3a4rfbQlToGn@MYBL2ei8gM)

Comment: A few more bytes if you re-arrange that last ternary operator and remove the center parenthesis: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##JclRCsIwDADQf48REBLmou5TbMVzjOHC7CRjS0s3BE9fBd/vm@Qt65A1bbXFZyijK@Z8y8z3nOWDRh0vkhAfByXnUffNDa5wAaAKauAcUpAN9dhQ9c/feSAqQ7Q1zoHn@MIRzyfiKar1u57KFw)

Comment: @Oliver Lol, rly!

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 90 bytes

```cs
a=>{for(int i=0;i<a;i++){var s=new String('-',i/2);Console.WriteLine(i%2<1?s+">":"<"+s);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc29CsIwFEDh2T7FpSBNqPWnbqatFCdBFxWcQ0zlgiaQe61I8dlrEbqe4TuGMuOD7V@E7g7nD7F9KjAPTQQ1dBGxZjRQG0bvCnRcQQNlr8uqa3wQQwAslwoLrTBNZdfqAFQ6@4Yzh4EUSZbMcJFLtfOO/MPOrwHZHtBZgdO8WG0pjat4ExdxSlJ9v70an63HGxw1OiG7aNKIAWht4PnF7x2vczGCJ6tvf09KqaJBWC1/)

Uses an [Action delegate](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1) to pull in the input and not require a return.

Ungolfed:

```cs
a => {
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)          // from [0, a)
    {
        var s = new String('-', i / 2);     // create string of dashes of length (a / 2)
        Console.WriteLine(i % 2 < 1 ?       // write arrow
                                s + ">" :       // if i is even: dashes plus ">"
                                "<" + s);       // if i is odd: "<" plus dashes
    }
}
```

Comment: [89 bytes](https://tio.run/##Nc29CsIwFEDh2T7FpSBNqPWnbqatFCdBFxWcQ0zlgiaQe61I8dlrEbqe4TuGMuOD7V@E7g7nD7F9KjAPTQQ1dBGxZjRQG0bvCnRcQQNlr8uqa3wQQwAslwrTtNBKdq0OQKWzbzhzGESRZMkMF7lUO@/IP@z8GpDtAZ0VOM2L1ZbSuIo3cRGnJNX326tx2Xq8wVGjE7KLJo0YgNYGnl/83vE6FyN4svr296SUKhqE1fIH "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Doesn't work, missing the first ">" output string.

Comment: [How about this instead?](https://tio.run/##Nc29CsIwFEDh2T7FpSBNqPWnbqatFCdBFxWcQ0zlgiaQe61I8dlrEbqe4TuGMuOD7V@E7g7nD7F9KjAPTQQ1dBGxZjRQG0bvCnRcQQNlr8uqa3wQQwAslwoLrWTX6gBUOvuGM4fBE0mWzHCRS7XzjvzDzq8B2R7QWYFpOs2L1ZbSuIo3cRGnJNX326tx2Xq8wVGjE7KLJo0YiNYGnl/83vE6FyN5svr2F6WUKhqE1fIH "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
F…> <N'-×.ø#`})s£»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f7VHDMjsFGz913cPT9Q7vUE6o1Sw@tPjQ7v//jQE)

---

```
F            }     # Loop from 0 to input...
 …> <              # Push '> <'...
     N'-×          # Push "-" multiplied by N.
         .ø        # Surround with this.
           #`      # Split on spaces, flatten both directions to stack.
              )    # Group all entries together after loop.
               s£  # Take first N.
                 » # Print with newlines.
```

---

Non-iterative, same byte-count:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
'-×©'>«.s®'<ìη.ιs£
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//yctw5fCqSc@wqsuc8KuJzzDrM63Ls65c8Kj//8z)

**Other, other method:**

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
'-×'>«.sð«.º€#˜s£
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXffwdHW7Q6v1ig9vAJKHdj1qWqN8ek7xocX//xsDAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 69 bytes

```cs
i=>{for(var s="";i>0;s+=--i%2<1?"-":"")WriteLine(i%2<1?"<"+s:s+">");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcixCsMgFAXQvV8hFwKKCElHnxqyZ@9cROEtBnzSJfTb7dIzniwuC88jD75a4DaSqipOjumuV9efd1cSAeK0ktjoHC/PsO1w8IB5dR7l5Fb0vwOseLFIMPSd9Kh6Ww3NHw)

Uses a technique from [Meerkat's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177594/8340), but has a lot of improvements.

Less golfed code:

```cs
// anonymous function with
// input i and no return value
i=>{
  for(
    // s is a string of hyphens
    var s="";
    // loop from i down to 0
    i>0;
    // decrement i and conditionally
    // tack on an additional hyphen
    // depending on whether i
    // is even or odd
    s+=--i%2<1?"-":""
  )
    // print the hyphens with an arrow
    // at the start or end, depending
    // on whether i is even or even
    WriteLine(i%2<1?"<"+s:s+">");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 36 bytes

```perl
say$|--?v17^($@.='-'):"$@>"for 1..<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVKlRlfXvszQPE5DxUHPVl1XXdNKScXBTiktv0jBUE/Pxu7/f/N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Gets `<` from the bitwise-xor of `-` and `v17` (ASCII 17).

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 99 bytes

```
proc A i {time {puts [expr [incr j]%2?"":"<"][string repe - [expr ($j-1)/2]][expr $j%2?">":""]} $i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BCsIwFAX3OcUjfEEXRVpdiSg9R/wLCUES2m9IIwghZ4@KXQ7MMNlOrcX0tBjhUbKfHUp85QXGvWOC8WITAm@Gq9YnfdZslpy8PJBcdOhWbUuh63f7gfnPFH7B5VtoriBf2zTfIwRF9eqgjqqul5uQqBEktX0A)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>123</s> <s>120</s> 119 bytes

```
n->{String l="",r="";for(int c=0;c<n;c++)System.out.println(c%2<1?r=c<1?">":c<2?"<":"-"+r:(l+=c<1?">":c<2?"<":"-"));}
```

Comment: In `r=c<1?">":c==1?` -- I think if `c<1`, equivalent to `c==0`, is excluded, `c==1` is equivalent to `c<2`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech -  true, I updated it. thanx.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 44 bytes

```perl
map{$_/=2;say'<'x/\./,'-'x$_,'>'x!$&}0..<>-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaJV7f1si6OLFS3Ua9Qj9GT19HXVe9QiVeR91OvUJRRa3WQE/Pxk7X8P9/83/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 47 bytes

```ruby
->n{n.times.map{|x|"<#{?-*n}>"[x%2*~x/=2,x+1]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOk@vJDM3tVgvN7GguqaiRslGudpeVyuv1k4pukLVSKuuQt/WSKdC2zC2tvZ/QWlJsUJatHnsfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 113 bytes

```php
<?php $x=fgets(STDIN);for($i=0;$i<$x;){echo $i%2<1?str_repeat("-",$i++/2).">\n":"<".str_repeat("-",$i++/2)."\n";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0BBpcI2LT21pFgjOMTF00/TOi2/SEMl09bAWiXTRqXCWrM6NTkjX0ElU9XIxtC@uKQovii1IDWxRENJV0lHJVNbW99IU0/JLiZPyUrJRkkPlwKgvHXt//9G5gYA)

A pretty straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 99 bytes

```
n=>new string[n].Select((x,i)=>(i%2>0?"<":"")+new String('-',(int)Math.Floor(i/2d))+(i%2<1?">":""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNSwMxED03vyIsSBO6jbbgxf3oobSiWBH24EF6iOlYB3YnmGRbpfS3r9lWRJzDwMx783hvjB8b66BrPdKWV18@QJOxv5N6QPr4t5rbugYT0JJXt0Dg0GTM1Np7/uTs1umG8ViHU@/LBx3Q8J3FDV9pJOGDi3ova67d1stf3oENBsuWTI4U0rsFtQ04/VpDfuaXJX@LaNFRURLs@Y8KrVUFvSEhPlOURSnwYlpezZI8uUkSOeqp1YkqhuNhKqK4XOnwrpa1tU7g5XQj5ag/yiezpDwdyS5j85jP1qCeHQaIbwBxVlH3NkZY0A6dpQYoqEfY93jauxOTayllxgZHduy@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>76</s> <s>73</s> <s>72</s> 67 bytes

```php
for(;$x<$i;)echo$x&1?'<':'',str_repeat('-',$x/2),$x++&1?'':'>',"
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoJBaVJRfFF@UWpBfVJKZl65hoGmtoJJpa2hi/T8tv0jDWqXCRiXTWjM1OSNfpULN0F7dRt1KXV2nuASsKTWxRENdV11HpULfSBNIamuDlABV2KnrKHEpWf//DwA)

Output:

```php
>
<
->
<-
-->
<--
--->
<---
---->
<----
----->
<-----
------>
<------
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```lua
for i=0,...-1 do a=("-"):rep(i//2)print(i%2<1 and a..">"or"<"..a)end
```

---

#### Explanation

```lua
for i=0,...-1 do  -- for 'i' going from 0 to the number on the first argument
  dashes = ("-"):rep(i//2)  -- dashes is a dash repeated by the iteration we are divided by 2 and rounded down
  print(i%2<1 and dashes..">" or "<"..dashes)  -- if 'i' is even, then print the dashes and then the right-facing arrow
                                               -- else, print the left-facing arrow and then the dashes
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctLCoAgEADQqwwDgUKOfXahXSRaDGghhIbZ@af2710vy1U4PK2mfG6bHKVC8kNPRGaEUIC9QoN6qfFWydpJ379sKnWTG4FzACbCFUtFh0SsYw6y7@r/WmT@AA)

Comment: Changed my solution! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, <strike>152</strike> 142 bytes

```
|n|{for i in 0..n{println!("");if i%2==1{print!("<");for _ in 1..i{print!("-");}}else{for _ in 1..i{print!("-");}print!(">");}}println!("");};
```

Down from 152 bytes to 142 bytes thanks to Pavel.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rust, but it looks like you have a lot of extra spaces: Around `%`, around `{` and `}`

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 102 bytes

command line options added `-n -d`

```php
<?for(;$i++<$argv[1];){$b=str_repeat("-",abs($u=ceil($i/2)*pow(-1,$i+1))-1);echo($u>0)?"<$b
":"$b>
";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxNCsIwEEDhfU8hYRaJbbAR3Jj@HEREmhrbgGTCNOpCvLpjcf@@l@bE3PQ3JGkhlGUDA03Pkzlb9QbXLpku5JMfshRaVINbJDza0Ye7hLDbq23Cl9SmWqlRShtl/Tjj2nS16kUDrhBHAa4rhP0w8@GLKQeMC@vrxhPh/46UQ5zamnX8AQ)

**Explanation**

It is not a much different solution, but is using one of the ways to get the n-th term of the series [A001057](https://oeis.org/A001057) wich is another way to look at the challenge.

According to A001057 the one way to obtain the n-th term is with the formula `a($n)=ceil($n/2)*pow(-1,$n+1)`.

And you can look at the challenge like this.

```php
>     +1
<     -1
->    +2
<-    -2
-->   +3
<--   -3
--->  +4
<---  -4
----> +5  
# And so on
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 31 bytes

```
qi{A2%{'<'-A2/*}{'-A2/*'>}?N}fA
```

Explanation:

```
qi{A2%{'<'-A2/*}{'-A2/*'>}?N}fA e# Whole code
qi                              e# Get input as an integer
  {                         }fA e# A for loop, from 0 - (input - 1), stored in var A
   A2%                          e# Is A a multiple of 2?
      {        }{        }?     e# Ternary operator: Left is true, right is false
      {
       '<                       e# Push "<" onto the stack
         '-                     e# Push "-" onto the stack
           A2/                  e# Get A/2
              *                 e# Repeat "-" A/2 times
               }{
                 '-             e# Push "-" onto the stack
                   A2/          e# Get A/2
                      *         e# Repeat "-" A/2 times
                       '>       e# Push ">" onto the stack
                         }
                           N    e# Push a new line after each arrow
                                e# Implicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzCz2tFItVrdRl3X0Uhfq7YaQqvb1dr71aY5/v9vbAoA)